# RFC 8767 and RFC 2308 about negative caching

Tags: domain-name-system

The RFC 8767 does not mention the negative caching.
Can I serve response from negative cache as stale data?

Let's say I have "abc.com" in my cache with a NXDOMAIN code and TTL expired, can I server it if I cannot currently resolve "abc.com"?

Answer (score 0):

My take on the lack of explicit mention of negative responses is that it's simply not considered different and that negative responses are handled the same as positive responses in this regard.